# Insert nodes in a specific area

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

```
<POW>
  <PPE>
    <UID>a1</UID>
    <ppe1Bool></ppe1Bool>
    <ppe1>hello</ppe1>
    <ppe2Bool></ppe2Bool>
    <ppe2></ppe2>
  </PPE>
  <PPE>
    <UID>a3</UID>
    <ppe1Bool></ppe1Bool>
    <ppe1>goodbye</ppe1>
    <ppe2Bool></ppe2Bool>
    <ppe2></ppe2>
  </PPE>
</PWO>
```

How can I insert a new parent with children between the two parent nodes above?
So it will read:

```
<POW>
 <PPE>
   <UID>a1</UID>
   <ppe1Bool></ppe1Bool>
   <ppe1>hello</ppe1>
   <ppe2Bool></ppe2Bool>
   <ppe2></ppe2>
 </PPE>
 <PPE>
   <UID>a2</UID>
   <ppe1Bool></ppe1Bool>
   <ppe1>new insert</ppe1>
   <ppe2Bool></ppe2Bool>
   <ppe2></ppe2>
 </PPE>
 <PPE>
   <UID>a3</UID>
   <ppe1Bool></ppe1Bool>
   <ppe1>goodbye</ppe1>
   <ppe2Bool></ppe2Bool>
   <ppe2></ppe2>
 </PPE>
</PWO>
```

I have this:

```
public static void insertRowBeforRowPPE(string strSelection, string strFileName)
{
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

 doc.Load(strFileName);
 XmlNodeList lstNode = doc.SelectNodes("PWO/PPE");
 foreach (XmlNode node in lstNode)
 {
     if (node["UID"].InnerText == strSelection)
     {
          //insert code
     }
 }
 doc.Save(strFileName);
}
```

strSelection will tell me what child to insert above it's parent....Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: the `PWO` in the xml should be `POW` at the end

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ2XML

```
public static void insertRowBeforRowPPE(string strSelection, string strFileName)
{

    XElement doc=XElement.Load(strFileName);
    foreach(XElement elm in doc.Elements("PPE"))
    {
        if(elm.Element("UID").Value==strSelection)
        elm.AddBeforeSelf(new XElement("PPE",new XElement("UID","a2")));
        //adds PPE node having UID element with value a2 just before the required node
    }
    doc.Save(strFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**USING LINQ**

To Insert a `Node` after a specific Node(`insert after a1`)

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");

xDoc.Element("POW")
     .Elements("PPE").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Element("UID").Value == "a1")
     .AddAfterSelf(new XElement("PPE", new XElement("UID", "A")
                                       , new XElement("ppe1Bool")
                                       , new XElement("ppe1", "hello"), 
                                         new XElement("ppe2Bool"),
                                         new XElement("ppe2")));                

 xDoc.Save("mod.xml");
```

As a side note your xml doesnt seem to be well formed and you need to correct it before using LINQ on it.